# Modeling redox transistor in SPICE

Tags: transistors

So i was reading a few papers regarding redox transistors and I would like to model one in spice. However, I don't know how exactly to do it. Looking at [this](https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/1458083), there is a sample schematic in the implementation figure:
[image: redox tranistor]

I am looking for some pointers on how to possibly model this in spice. Obviously, this would be better to model in TCAD software, but I am not aware of any free solution. Does anybody have any idea? Thanks :)

Comment: The link to that article points to a login page (if not even a paywall, I didn't bother to check). Please do not assume people here will want to go all the effort to get to the article. Your link should point to freely accessible resources, otherwise people here could entirely ignore your post. At least provide an excerpt of the article inside your post. When you post on this site you should show effort and provide the best level of information you can.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati Thanks. I will try to find somethig else, but the article is indeed behind a paywall. I even think that most of articles about redox transistors are behind paywall as well.

Comment: IANAL, but I think you could post some relevant excerpts without copyright infringements (under the fair use principle) if proper citation is given.